# How do I tell InstallShield to overwrite existing registry values?

Tags: registry, installshield

When I run my simple MSI installer it adds a collection of values to the Registry. If I manually alter them and then re-install those values are not overwritten. How do I tell InstallShield to overwrite these values?

Comment: Hi Peter, was your problem resolved?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have no recollection, and I work elsewhere now so I can't look.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the registry key name (the folder icon) and select "Automatic" option. This will make sure that it is being written every time you install.